Is this a standard feature in C
I can't understand if this feature is standard or only some weird stuff.
struct A {
    int field_1;
    int field_2;
};

struct B {
    struct A super;
};

int main() {
    struct B b;

    // Normally i must access like that to field_2
    b.super.field_2 = 10;
    
    // Is legal to access in this manner?
    struct A* generic_ref = (struct A*)&b;
    generic_ref->field_2 = 10;

    return 0;
}

I tried on gcc and it seems to work, but i think that can be something that can break in some more complicated situations.

Yes, it's standard. A pointer to a struct is also a pointer to its first member.

This is allowed, as a pointer to a struct can be converted to a pointer to its first member.
This is specifically spelled out in section 6.7.2.1p15 of the C standard:

A pointer to a
structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member


So i can replicate that to how many level i want? For example a struct A in a struct B in a struct C and i can use a pointer of struct A to store a reference to an instance of struct C?

@Tonaion Yes, if the first member of struct C is of type struct B, then a struct C * can be converted to a struct A * to reference that member.

The C standard guarantees that there is no padding before the first member of a struct (§ 6.7.2.1: Structure and union specifiers, paragraph 13):

Within a structure object, the non-bit-ﬁeld members and the units in which bit-ﬁelds
reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a
structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
bit-ﬁeld, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed
padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

Emphasis mine.
In other words, if you dereference a pointer to a struct B contains another struct, struct A as its first and/or only member, as if it were a struct A, the resulting struct A would be populated as you would expect...

While it is true that the first member of a structure must start at the same address as the structure because there is no padding, this is insufficient to guarantee the behavior OP asks about. Before you can “dereference a pointer to a struct B… as if it were a struct A,” some conversion or other transformation must occur, because dereferencing a pointer to a struct B produces an lvalue for a struct B, thus accessing the structure as a struct B, not as a struct A…

… So you need to make an lvalue for a struct A by one means or another, and you need a guarantee from the C standard that this means will work. This post does not speak to that. The fact there is no padding does not guarantee that converting a pointer to a struct B to the type pointer to struct A will produce the required pointer.
